# Circumvent Excel's 255 count limit on chart series in an OOXML XSLX

Tags: excel, charts, openxml, series, xlsx

When generating a valid OOXML document with a sheet that contains a http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart `ScatterChart` with more than 255 series (`c:ser`), Excel 365 fails to open the XLSX correctly by showing a prompt that asks to repair the file. Repair fails and the drawing part is being removed. I eventually found a confirmation of this observation through the Office implementation notes on the OOXML standard: ([2.1.1531 Part 1 Section 21.2.2.161, scatterChart (Scatter Charts)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a25f022-e56d-4b75-8361-c2d5beab1060)):

```
a.   The standard states that the maxOccurs value for the ser child element is unbounded.

Office limits the occurrences of this element to 255.
```

I have tried to use multiple charts but this has not worked, although I did not find a limitation for charts similar to the above note on series. If I have less than 255 series, I can put them in multiple charts (just insert `</c:scatterChart><c:scatterChart>` between `</c:ser>` and `<c:ser>`) as long as the order counter is globally correct and does not restart with each chart. However Excel complains again when exceeding the total order count with more than 255 series and offers the same repair prompt, which does not repair the chart but removes it.

Any ideas how to achieve a scatter chart with more than 255 curves?